# Backend error (Dismiss) when using PageSpeed Insights

Tags: google-pagespeed

I got this message trying to analyse a website in the google's tool. Can't get any data. I tryed it with and without https, www.

Sorry for not giving more info. Only got this message, not a code error or something more specific. Any clue?